# How to share Bamboo job artifacts between two jobs on the SAME stage?

Tags: bamboo

This article covers [Sharing Artifacts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html#Sharingartifacts-job) between two Bamboo jobs on two "different" stages. However, how do I share artifacts between two jobs on the SAME stage?

Answer (score 3):

In general jobs run in parallel. Bamboo will not synchronize them by artifact.